# How to calculate two numbers without using any calculation buttons in android studio

Tags: android

I have coded a program that calculates the values of 1st and 2nd text box and display the result in 3rd text box after taping the "Add" button. But I want to display the result into the 3rd text box as soon as I start typing in 1st or 2nd text box automatically, without using any buttons. I know this is possible, because many calculator apps are there, that do the expected work. My code is given bellow. Just want to remove the "ADD" button and do the calculation automatically. Please help me...

### "activity_main.xml" code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.saptarshi.test.MainActivity">



    <LinearLayout
       android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1">
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/t1"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:hint="1st number" />
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/t2"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:hint="2nd number" />
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/t3"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:hint="Total" />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Add"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:onClick="add" />

</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

### "MainActivity.Java" Code

```
public void add(View view){
        EditText a = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.t1);
        EditText b = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.t2);
        EditText c = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.t3);
        int x = Integer.parseInt(a.getText().toString());
        int y = Integer.parseInt(b.getText().toString());
        int z = x+y;
        c.setText(Integer.toString(z));
    }
```

Comment: read about `Textwatchers`

Comment: you can use addTextChangedListener() with edittext

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use following code for both of your EditText s

```
edittext.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
            int count) {
        if(!s.equals("") )
                { //do your work here }
        }

    }

    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
            int after) {

    }

    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use TextWatcher to your EditText, see example below

```
TextWatcher autoAddTextWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        int value1 = Integer.parseInt(editText1.getText().toString());
        int value2 = Integer.parseInt(editText2.getText().toString());
        editText3.setText(value1 + value2);
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

    }
};

editText1.addTextChangedListener(autoAddTextWatcher);
editText2.addTextChangedListener(autoAddTextWatcher);
```

It might be better if you check if EditText is empty, so your application will not force closed. Example:

```
int value1 = TextUtils.isEmpty(editText1.getText().toString()) ? 0 : Integer.parseInt(editText1.getText().toString());
```

And don't forget to add

```
android:inputType="number"
```

to your EditText's XML to limit user input to number, so there will be no NumberFormatException.

Comment: thnks for the information

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this:

```
    a.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                if (!b.getText().toString().equals("") && !a.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                    c.setText(String.valueOf(Integer.valueOf(a.getText().toString()) + Integer.valueOf(b.getText().toString())));
                }    
                }

                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

                }
            });
```

Comment: nice... job done.. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use a **TextWatcher**. It allows us to monitor the changes made to the text in any EditText at runtime. The TextWatcher works as a listener which is attached to your EditText and provides you with the ability to monitor the changes made to the respective EditText.

It contains 3 methods, which are as follows:

**1. afterTextChanged():** This method is called after the text has been changed.

**2. beforeTextChanged():** This method is called when the text is about to be updated by some new text.

**2. onTextChanged():** This method is called when the text is just updated.

**Example:**

```
editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    });
```

Use the method, onTextChanged() for performing the required calculation.

[More info on TextWatcher](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html).